# OpenVPN: How edit the server.conf and client.conf parameters to point to generated key files?

Tags: configuration, openvpn

I am trying to complete the [installation and configuration of OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html). The OpenVPN guide says,

> Before you use the sample configuration file, you should first edit the ca, cert, key, and dh parameters to point to the files you generated in the PKI section above.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the sample client and server configuration files that are to be edited before use, are located here on my machine for OpenVPN.

`/usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/client.conf
/usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/sample-config-files/server.conf.gz/server.conf`

The generated files that are referred to in the PKI section of VPN are the keys. So I presume the configuration parameters must point to this path below.

`/usr/share/doc/openvpn/easy-rsa-old-master/easy-rsa/2.0/keys`

Did I correctly identify the files that need to be edited before use as well as the proper location the parameters of the configuration file must point to?

If so, then how can I locate these  **ca, cert, key, and dh** configuration parameters and how do I point them to the key files I generated?

Comment: No, the keys can't be under `/usr`, they are specific to your computer, they are located under `/etc`. Are you installing OpenVPN from a distribution or building from source? Are you configuring a server, a client, or both on separate machines?

Comment: I'm building 1 server, and three clients. OpenVPN was installed via Debian using the apt package manager. And I downloaded easy-rsa off a website to generate the keys.

Comment: So how do I point the client and server configuration parameters to the correct location? The  OpenVPN guide said that their example configuration files are a fine starting point. Could you show me how to do such a thing?